# Updating documents using nested JSON or dotted keys

Tags: json, mongodb

Suppose I have a doc structure like this:

```
thing: {
  name: {
    first: "John",
    last: "Doe"
  }
}
```

say I want to update the last name only. Which command do I send to update?

```
$set: {
  name: {
    first: "Connor"
  }
}
```

or

```
$set: {
  "name.first": "Connor"
}
```

Is there a difference? Or a preference? I much prefer the first since it resembles the actual document, but mongodb documentation uses the second method.

Comment: You meant to write MongoDb uses the first method, right?  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set

Comment: hmmm well i guess they use both. is there a difference?

Comment: The difference is that the first option will delete your last name, since you're setting name to the object after it, which only contains first.

Comment: Also, I think you meant "update the first name only", above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$set` command will take the key and overwrite whatever was stored in it by the value you pass. So in this case

```
$set: {
  name: {
    first: "Connor"
  }
}
```

the whole subdocument `name` with potentially rich structure is getting replaced with a simple  `{first: 'Connor'}`.

Similar thing is happening in the second case, only it is one level deeper. In this case it's a string, but it could be a hash as well.

```
$set: {
  "name.first": "Connor"
}
```

You can update fields at arbitrary depth level by constructing proper dotted name. Here's a slightly contrived example

```
db.collection.update(query, {$set: {'stats.daily.20120622.mainpage.visited': 1}});
```